# SQLite-db corrupt only on Android 2.2

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) method to copy a pre-existing sqlite-database from my assets-directory to the app's /databases/-directory on the first app launch. This works fine on emulators with different SDK-levels and on my 4.4 devices, but fails on a 2.2.2 device with the following logcat message:

`sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption found by source line 40107`
and further on `SELECT locale FROM android_metadata failed`

There are other SO-questions with this error, but my database definitely contains an `android_metadata`-table with a `locale` column and an `en_US` entry (which is why the app works on many other emulators and higher-SDK devices) and isn't large (32KB), which I read can be an issue.

**Update:** I switched to using the [SQLiteAssetHelper-library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), but am still getting the same error:

> copying database from assets...
>
> database copy complete
>
> sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption found by source line 40107
>
> sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed
>
> CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
>
> Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database

It seems the `SQLiteOpenHelper` (not the `AssetHelper`) is trying to create the `android_metadata` table (even though it's already present) and fails because of this?

**Update 2:** The full stacktrace can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/qRQgQ0cJ)

Comment: I suggest [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I switched to using the library, but am still getting the same error: `copying database from assets...

database copy complete

sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption found by source line 40107

sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed

CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed

Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database`, so it seems the issue is indeed with my db? It's strange that it's working fine one higher SDK-versions, though.

Comment: How are you creating the database?

Comment: It's created on an iPhone (in order to conform to iOS's Data-Model specifications). I then pull it from the device, change all PKs to `_id` and add a new `android_metadata`-table with a `locale`-column and an `en_us`-row. I know this doesn't sound "optimal", but iOS needs the db to be in a specific format and I need to ship a db with the app, rather than populating an empty db after the app has been installed. Could the problem be related to different sqlite-file-versions (i.e. the iPhone may create a sqlite-vX-file, while Android 2.2 can only deal with sqlite <vY?

Answer (score 0):

> and add a new android_metadata-table with a locale-column and an en_us-row

Now that you are using `SQLiteAssetHelper`, and given the error message (`CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed`), remove your manual `android_metadata` table from your packaged copy of the database. This will be created for you as part of unpacking the database via `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. I removed the `android_metadata`-table from the db and uninstalled and reinstalled the app, but then error is still the same (`sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption found by source line 40107; CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed`)

Comment: @Nick: Could you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: I just tried the new db on different emulators: It works fine on 3.0+, but fails with the above error on 2.2.2 and 2.3.7. I'm not too worried about 2.2-compatibility for obvious reasons, but Gingerbread-support is still comparatively important. I've updated the main question with the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Nick: I do not know what could be going wrong for you at this point. My own book sample is for API Level 11+, as I am using the native `CursorLoader` implementation, so I do not have a convenient pointer for you to a sample that will run on API Level 10.

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway for your patience and pointers! The `SQLiteAssetHelper`-library was a great piece of advice, it definitely looks more robust than my previous implementation!